# How can I affix this wood transition piece?

Tags: wood, tile, transition

[image]I made a perfect looking transition to go from wood floating floor to tile for a bathroom.  Problem is that this is where the old marble transition was.  Can I set the transition with mortar?  If not what can I use?  Right now there is a one inch deep hole.

New Edit - in picture i have tile to the right, then gap, then floated maple.  In the gap there used to be a marble transition that had about 1.5 inches of mortar under it.  The concrete under this mortar is in very bad shape - probably the reason why the thick bed of mortar.  I scraped some mortar over while tiling - i could remove this easily but not sure it helps.  It is too deep to just adhere wood L transition to the floor.

Comment: just wanted to add that i know i could use a concrete anchor but really would like to not drill through this transition.  I guess worse case scenario is I put it in with mortar and it eventually come loose and then i have to drill it in right?  Would like to do it right the first time though.

Comment: You want to install the new transition on top of the old transition? A picture might be useful.

Comment: [Construction Adhesive](http://www.samanthamuse.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Liquid-Nails-Liquid-Nails-Heavy-Duty-Construction-Adhesive.jpeg)

Comment: What is the height differential between the tile and the maple?

Comment: less than an 1/8th of an inch.

Comment: Then a simple "T" molding will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view of the new information, I would remove the mortar in the gap.  Seal the edge of the wood floor at the sub floor with a waterproof caulk  and use a funnel and [self leveling (cement based) underlayment](http://www.laticrete.com/architects/products/self_leveling_patching_mortars.aspx) to make a flat base. Tape both sides of the gap with some blue tape to make any cement spillage an easy cleanup. When setup (24-48 hr) and well cured, attach the transition to the gap, I prefer the polyurethane adhesives ([PL](http://www.loctiteproducts.com/p/pl_ca_prem/overview/Loctite-PL-Premium-Polyurethane-Construction-Adhesive.htm)) over LN.  (It is stronger, stickier and more flexible, over time).

As noted previously by Tester101 in chat, weight the transition in place overnight.

Comment: that may be the way i go... just sucks because people need to use this bathroom tomorrow.  I can't really grout until this piece is in and it is the only thing holding this up.  So dumb that a little transition holds everything up.  I can't really see how I could have installed it first.  I needed to know where my tiles would be.

Comment: Actually, I use tile installed transitions, Schluter makes a ton of them, that go under the tile and separate the tile and wood.  There are sloped transitions for level matching and simple L shapes for different materials : http://www.schluter.com/137.aspx

Comment: Going to the big box to see what they have.  I am actually looking for a T bracket that I can put upside down - so I can screw from both sides and then glue the crap out of.  Lets says I bought a schluter T transition... how would I set that in place?

Comment: And I didn't even look at the schluter stuff before because my transition looks great.  But I bet they had something that would have helped hold my transition in place...  I will never do another floor without starting with the transitions.

Comment: http://www.schluter.com/1_3_reno_t_installation.aspx.  Kerdi-fix is a rubberlike sealant/adhesive.  You could substitute driveway crack filler, like http://www.homedepot.com/hdus/en_US/DTCCOM/HomePage/Brand_Pages/Sika/Docs/Sealants_Adhesives_How-To.pdf

Comment: The flooring department will have that universal molding piece (discussed in chat) that is laminate and mounts to a u channel

Comment: Thanks for your help Herr - I put down about 1/4 inch of leveling compound with a schluter L placed on top.  I didn't firmly set it in there because I want the poly to bind the bottom (or some) to the leveling compound and the rest to the transition.  Also I wanted to make sure the L stayed level or close.  I feel there will be a ton of coverage now.  And the L provides about a 1/4 inch gap to the float.  I will take some pictures tonight before and after I put the transition on... guess I can't grout until tomorrow.

Comment: the L cost $10 at Lowes - I have enough left over to use for at least 2 more doors... Those are carpet so much easier install.

Comment: So the fix in case anyone else needs it. 1- Get your mortar to about the right height - test your transition.  2 - Thin amount of pretty much any leveling agent. 3 - Press "L" (schluter) into leveling agent very lightly facing the tile with a 1/4 inch gap between L head and floating wood.  4. When leveling agent is cured douse a lot of poly (loctite construction adhesive) all over L.  5. Cut under door trim so transition barely fits 6- put it in firmly pushing it down and to the wood.  7. Put weights on it and spacers in gaps to tile - so wood is pressed on L.  8.  After cured then grout!

Answer (score 0):

I see a brass (or aluminum) L bracket (90 degree angle) across the width of the doorway, fastened on the flat, the thin edge pointing up, about 1/3 to 1/2 the thickness of the transition.  Cut a kerf across the bottom of the transition to locate the vertical edge of the L bracket.  Use a polyurethane adhesive to make a blind connection.

If you need to fill up the area from the old transition, mortar could be used, or a build up of wood to support the L bracket.

**edit** [typical aluminum angle stock](http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/catalog/servlet/Search?storeId=10051&langId=-1&catalogId=10053&keyword=aluminum%20angle&Ns=None&Ntpr=1&Ntpc=1&selectedCatgry=Search%20All)
[image: 1/8 x 1" x 96"]

Comment: where do you get a bracket like this?  Link would be great.

Comment: also had an idea and not to sure about it.  How about screws or roofing nails screwed in to the bottom of the head of the transition and anchor that in the mortar?

Comment: Screw (brass or stainless would work.  The drift pin technique (where you embed round pin(s) just after setting mortar) would allow adjustments because you'd be anchoring threshold after mortar has set.

Comment: wow I thought you were talking about a flooring specific bracket.  I have less than a half inch under the transition piece to attach to.  I think this would work but I don't think I trust myself lining this bracket up right and securing it to the ground at the exact right height.  Not saying it is a bad solution but seems to bring in extra variable to me.

Comment: The height is easily managed, as aluminum is easy to cut.  By screwing it down, its easily removed for adjustments.  The slot in the transition piece actually shouldn't be exactly the correct depth, the wood will 'move' with humidity through the year.  Better to leave a small gap on top.   A 1/8 thick bracket will match the cut from a typical table saw blade.